# R calculate probability of outcome=1 based on multiple variables present

Tags: r

I am quite new to R, I apologize if I am calling anything by the wrong terms.

I need to create a new column that represents the probability an outcome=1 based on 4 variables being present or not present (coded 0/1)

The baseline probability of outcome 1 occurring is 0.5.
If variable 1 or 2 is present, the prob. increases by 0.25 for each variable.
If variable 3 or 4 is present, the prob. decreases by 0.25 for each variable.

I have no idea how to go about calculating this new column. Any advice greatly welcomed.

My data is set up like this:

```
# var1 var2 var3 var4 prob
# 1    0    1    0    ?
# 1    0    0    1    ?
# 0    0    1    1    ?
# 1    1    0    1    ?
# 0    0    1    0    ?
```

Comment: Check my update, I think maybe your values are not of type numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix multiplication way.

```
df$prob <- 0.5 + 0.25*as.matrix(df[1:4]) %*% c(1,1,-1,-1)
df
#  var1 var2 var3 var4 prob
#1    1    0    1    0 0.50
#2    1    0    0    1 0.50
#3    0    0    1    1 0.00
#4    1    1    0    1 0.75
#5    0    0    1    0 0.25
```

Comment: I tried this however it returns "requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments"

Comment: @r-newbie That's why the df must be coerced to matrix with `as.matrix`. That error should go away. If not, try `df[1:4] <- lapply(df[1:4], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` first.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
# Load your example data
df <- read.table(header = TRUE,
text="var1 var2 var3 var4 prob
1    0    1    0    ?
1    0    0    1    ?
0    0    1    1    ?
1    1    0    1    ?
0    0    1    0    ?")

# Compute the prob (by your description)
df$prob <- 0.5 + 0.25*df$var1 + 0.25*df$var2 - 0.25*df$var3 - 0.25*df$var4
print(df)
#  var1 var2 var3 var4 prob
#1    1    0    1    0 0.50
#2    1    0    0    1 0.50
#3    0    0    1    1 0.00
#4    1    1    0    1 0.75
#5    0    0    1    0 0.25
```

The same thing can be achieved a bit more succinctly with

```
df <- within(df, prob <- 0.5 + 0.25*(var1 + var2 - var3 - var4))
```

Edit: (Even) more succinct thanks comments below.

Comment: Or even `0.25*(var1 + var2 - var3 - var4)`.

Comment: I tried all 3 of these, but I get "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**
I include the data set I used for this code so that you can check if there is any difference between our input data set and yours. Note that here column names can also be character strings.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
   ~var1, ~var2, ~var3, ~var4,
 1,    0,    1,    0,    
 1,    0,    0,    1,    
 0,    0,    1,    1,    
 1,    1,    0,    1,    
 0,    0,    1,    0
)


df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(prob = 0.5 + (var1 + var2) * 0.25 - (var3 + var4) * 0.25)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Rowwise: 
   var1  var2  var3  var4  prob
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     1     0  0.5 
2     1     0     0     1  0.5 
3     0     0     1     1  0   
4     1     1     0     1  0.75
5     0     0     1     0  0.25
```

I suspect maybe your values are not of type numeric. If that's the case use the following code before you apply any of the solutions mentioned:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric))
```

Comment: Tried this but it returns "non-numeric argument to binary operator"